# iPython print output appears in console in UTF-8

Tags: python, utf-8, ipython

After switching to UTF-8 using

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')
```

iPython will refuse to show the output of the print command in the iPython Console window but will show it in the console output of the corresponding python kernel. Is that a bug or a feature? And if the latter, how can I change it?

I am using spyder 2.3.4 and ipython-console 3.1.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, would you mind elabourating? ;)

Comment: It's not normal to change the default encoding in Python, and doing so may well break things that make assumptions about what the default encoding is. In this case, it's actually reloading `sys` that breaks IPython. What are you trying to achieve? It's likely that there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasK, I had trouble with processing Chinese text properly. I have, however, worked it out somewhat and make sure that everything is a unicode string, which pretty much solved my problems!

Comment: @jmaxx , I code the same issue. Cannot print any dataframe with non ascii content. ( unless using the sys reload trick which screw ipython stdout).  I am using python 2.7  . Any clue ?

Comment: @FredericBazin As stated above, I did not use the trick mentioned above but converted my non-ascii content (which were Chinese characters) to unicode by applying the decode/encode methods. So, basically, I manually ensured that the data would be stored as 'UTF-8' which was sufficient for me. Hope it helps...